# Integrating multiple DiracDelta functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

When I integrate the product of two `DiracDelta` functions, I get a single `DiracDelta`, i.e.,

> Integrate[DiracDelta[x-y] DiracDelta[x-z],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}] = DiracDelta[y-z]

as expected.

However, sometimes the integral of a product of DiracDelta functions does not give the correct result.  For instance one would expect:

> Integrate[DiracDelta[u+z(1-x)] DiracDelta[v-z y], {z,-Infinity,Infinity}] = DiracDelta[v(1-x)+u y]

but instead gets a convergence error:

```
"Integral of ... does not converge on {-infinity, infinity}".
```

The strange thing is, if you write this integral changing $x \to 1-x$, then you get the expected result:

> Integrate[DiracDelta[u+z x] DiracDelta[v-z y], {z,-Infinity,Infinity}] = DiracDelta[v x+u y]

What's going on?

Comment: Thank you David for editing my post to make it look better.

Comment: Smells buggy: if you replace `(1-x)`$\to$`f[x]`, the integral is also evaluated correctly.

Comment: Yeah. It is definitely a bug. But I am not sure how to get around this problem. I have hundreds of terms with two diracdeltas, and I cannot imagine doing this by hand.

Comment: The product od DiracDeltas has no sense. DiracDelta is not a usual function, but a distribution. It is well-known that multiplication of distributions is not defined. Moreover, even  a notation of such type Integrate[DiracDelta[x],{x,0,1}]  has no sense (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure ).

Comment: Well, I am not trying to consider whether diracdelta is mathematically well-defined object or not. Im merely saying it has an explicit rules and expected behaviors under integral, and mathematica seems to have a buggy features.

Comment: Let us call things by their proper names. Your question is of such kind: "What is the sum of a number and a three-dimensional vector?"

Comment: If you are disturbed by it, then just consider the delta function as a limit definition of exponent. Whether you are uncomfortable with Integrate[DiracDelta[x],{x,0,1}]  = 1 or not, that is what I am 'assuming' to be true and I do not want to debate any issues about distributions. Your points are beyond the issues of mathematica pointed out here.

Comment: @user64494 the product of distributions with disjoint singular support is perfectly well-defined. Such is the case of the distributions in the OP.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: Can you base your statement, giving us an accessible reference?

Comment: @user64494 theorem 1. in https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.1778

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: Thank you for the reference. However, I don't see why DiracDelta[u+z(1-x)] and DiracDelta[v-z y] in Integrate[DiracDelta[u+z(1-x)] *DiracDelta[v-z y], {z,-Infinity,Infinity}] have disjoint singular supports.

Comment: @user64494 $\delta_a$ has $\operatorname{sing}\operatorname{supp}\delta_a=\{a\}$, so $\delta_a\delta_b$ is well-defined as long as $a\neq b$. In this case, the first Delta has a singularity at $\frac{u}{1-x}$ and the second one at $\frac{v}{y}$.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: Yes, of course. But how about the case $\frac u {1-x} =\frac v y$?

Comment: @user64494 MMA doesn't test for such singular cases. Generically speaking, two symbolic variables are treated as different as far as DiracDelta is concerned. For example, the object `\DiracDelta[a-b]` is regarded as generically well-defined even though one could in principle ask "well, how about the case $a=b$?". Or for another example, MMA evaluates `Integrate[DiracDelta[x-a]f[a],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]` to `f[a]`, even though `f` may be singular at such point. MMA won't throw a warning message "`f` may be singular", just like it won't ask whether $\frac{u}{1-x}$ may be equal to $\frac{v}{y}$

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: Thank you for your info. However, the case $\frac u {1-x} =\frac v y \Leftrightarrow uy+v(1-x)=0,y\neq0,x\neq 1$ is crucial for the formula under consideration. In this case the LHS is undefined.

Comment: @user64494 sure. That's why `DiracDelta[v(1 - x) + u y]` is the "correct" output. If $v(1-x)=uy$, then both the LHS and the RHS are undefined; if, on the other hand, $v(1-x)\neq uy$ both the LHS and the RHS are well-defined and equal. Thus, we can say that in general they are identical. Strictly speaking, it doesn't make much sense to say that two undefined expressions are identical, but as far as MMA is concerned, this is the best we can do in general. E.g., if you type `x/x` in MMA you'll get `1`, which, strictly speaking, is only valid for $x\neq0$. But MMA won't consider such a case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73305/discussion-between-user64494-and-accidentalfouriertransform).

Comment: Because the chart is lost for me for certain reasons which are unknown to me, I'd like to stress that distributions are not usual functions. There is no sense in DiracDelata[0] and DiracDelta[1.1] and Integrate[DiracDelta[x],{x,-1,1}]. I consulted, in particular, professor Ya. Mykytyuk https://zbmath.org/authors/?q=ai:mykytyuk.yaroslav-v about the topic. One may contact him at yamykytyuk@yahoo.com with his kind permission.

Comment: @user64494 I know the indicator function is not smooth at $\pm1$, and that's why I said *mollified* indicator function. In any case, you don't need functions to be smooth everywhere to be in the domain of $\delta_a$; it suffices for them to be smooth at $a$.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: Sorry, your "modified indicator" is not defined by you at all. Did you contact Professor Ya. Mykytyuk?

Comment: @user64494 I said **mollified**, not **modified**. Have a look at the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) if you want. And no, I did not contact Mykytyuk, and I have no intention of doing so. I don't think they want any kind of unsolicited email from internet strangers, asking about very basic distribution theory facts.

Answer (score 1):

Dirty workaround:

```
integrand = DiracDelta[u + z (1 - x)] DiracDelta[v - z y];
Integrate[integrand /. x -> x + 1, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}] /. x -> (x - 1)

(* DiracDelta[v (1 - x) + u y] *)
```

A safer option, which should work quite generically, is

```
integrand = DiracDelta[u + z (1 - x)] DiracDelta[v - z y];
Integrate[integrand /. DiracDelta[a_ + b_ z] :> 1/Abs[b] DiracDelta[a/b + z], {z, -Infinity, Infinity}] /. 1/Abs[b_] DiracDelta[a_] :> DiracDelta[a b] // Simplify

(* DiracDelta[v - v x + u y] *)
```

--

More generally, the problem seems to be with the structure $1\pm A$, where $A$ may be either symbolic or numeric. For example, the integral

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[u + z (1 + \[Pi])] DiracDelta[v - z y], {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

is also returned unevaluated. On the other hand

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[u + z E] DiracDelta[v - z y], {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(* DiracDelta[E v + u y] *)
```

is calculated correctly.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76757/discussion-on-answer-by-accidentalfouriertransform-integrating-multiple-diracdel).